# Querying a string in a int field returns all rows containing 0 in that field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a simple search in all the fields of a table, but when I query an integer field it is returning me all the rows that have a 0 there. What is weird for me is that this doesn't happens with the id field, which doesn't retrieve anything in the case that it is a word (expected behaviour).

```
SELECT * FROM seats WHERE number = "2" - this works
SELECT * FROM seats WHERE number = "hello" - this brings all the zeros
SELECT * FROM seats WHERE id = "hello" - this brings nothing
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Tried to convert the string to an integer and used 0 when that failed instead of null or an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `number` has data type `int`, so:

```
WHERE number = "2"
```

is equivalent to:

```
WHERE number = 2
```

because MySql implicitly converts `"2"` to `2`, so to match `number`'s data type. 
Because the conversion succeeds to convert the string to the number it represents, you say that *it works*.
But here:

```
WHERE number = "hello"
```

the attempt to make an `int` out of `"hello"` results in `0`, so it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE number = 0
```

and you see that this *this brings all the zeros*.
Now in the case of `id`, if its data type is `varchar` then here:

```
WHERE id = "hello"
```

no conversion is done and because there is no `id` with the value `"hello"` *this brings nothing*.
If the `id`'s data type is `int` then again it is equivalent to:

```
WHERE id = 0
```

and I guess there is no `id` with value `0` so *this brings nothing*.
All this is explained here: [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing data types.  MySQL does silent conversion of strings to numbers, converting the leading digits to a number.  So `'2'` is converted to `2`.  As would `2million`.

If there are no leading digits, then the value is converted to `0`.

Moral?  Don't mix data types.  Use the appropriate data type for comparisons.

Comment: That's what i thought first, but what bugged me is why it doesn't work like that with the id? primary keys are treated differently?

Comment: @RubenGonzalez . . . There is no difference.  I would guess either that the `id` has no `0` value or it is a string and not a number.